# Filament being pushed back out the filament hole

Tags: filament, extruder, hotend

I just got a Monoprice Maker Select v2 off eBay for $200 and I'm very happy with it (so far). I'm learning a lot, but I've run into this problem that I cannot solve:

When I put filament into the extruder (it's a direct drive extruder), it works well for a minute or two and then the extruder pushes it back out the entrance hole where it should be inserted.

I have no idea why it's doing this. The weird thing is when it's being pushed back out it curls up, maybe from being pushed back up and being hot? It is unclear to me why it curls.

What I have tried:

- Multiple brands of filament but nothing is working (I'm not sure what type of nozzle is on the Maker Select v2 but I have printed a Benchy once before this with no problems);
- Unclogging - I took the cold end off and nothing looks jammed in it;
- Pushed a guitar string through the hot end and no jams.

I cannot figure out why it's doing this.

Comment: forgot to mention, im using solutech and amz3d pla filament at 200-210 c and it just keeps pushing itself back out the top of the extruder.

Comment: i have the printer plugged into the computer via usb and cura is sending commands for what to do. i figured cura could be messing up so i deleted the profile and restarted cura and am trying again. maybe this will help? would gcode from an sdcard be better?

Comment: so i took the fan off the side of the extruder and held the cold end in place so it wouldnt move and ran a print. i could see what the cold end was doing and it ran the motor in reverse and pushed the filament out. why would it do this?

Comment: Please copy-paste the comments in the main body of your question. And format you question so it's readable rather than a solid blob of text. Then remove the comments. :)

Comment: Also: when looking at the stepper running in reverse: does it push the filament back out in a long, single swoosh or it appears to do the usual move-stop-move-again movements typical of the extruder stepper, simply in reverse?  What happens then?  Does the print resume spinning the stepper forward or keeps on in reverse, or yet it stops the print completely?

Comment: May I suggest trying a micro SD card such as the one that came with the printer. I've had problems when connecting a computer directly.

Comment: Please answer @mac 's question and put it in the main body of the question, maybe also post pictures or (a link to) a video.

Comment: Does it push the filament out until if cannot (because there is no more loaded filament), or does it return to pushing it back in for a while?  In other words, is it in some sense cyclical (in-out-in-out), or in-until-event-then-out-until-you-stop-it?

Comment: In until event then out and stays out until I restart

Comment: I got an idea: Maybe the heat crawls back so that the extruder can still push it out the entrence (no resistent) but don't get grip to push it in the nozzle direction, because it is to soft and deformed.

Answer (score 2):

Change the retraction distance, maybe you have a too long distance, that pushes the filament the whole way out.

Comment: retraction is set to 6.5 mm for cura 3.2.1. is this good or bad?

Comment: @user25832 That is the Cura default, that value works well on my Ultimaker 3. But I doubt that this is the issue, throats are generally longer than 6.5 mm